# How to read all CSV files in on-prem file system to SQL Server with Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have Copy Data task reading json files from on-prem file server to SQL Server. I have 100 CSV files to be read and inserted data to single database table as a row.

Copy Data Source:

```
-Source dataset "json_dataset"
-Folder "FolderName"
-Filename ""
-File path in dataset "selected"
-Recursively "selected"
```

I get error if filename is "*" :

```
"*" does not conform to the naming rules by the data store 'FileServer
```

If it is empty:

```
"No value provided for parameter Filename"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dataset parameter for the filename in the source dataset and provide the value from the copy data activity dataset properties.

[image]

[image]